# Google Form validation with url query

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-forms

Sorry for my lack of precise wording but I'm not really familiar with HTML/js/app script.

We work with plenty of clients every month and organize events with them. Each one of our clients has a unique code which is necessary in order to take part in our events.

We heavily rely on Google Forms in order to let clients book their spots. On the form, we ask for their code but we do not have any kind of validation.

Recently we've been given access to a database API that works with URL queries (e.g., [www.mydatabase.com/q=CODE](http://www.mydatabase.com/q=CODE)). If the "CODE" is valid then a nonempty JSON value is returned.

I was looking for a way to use google form [validation feature](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864?hl=en) with the URL query.
I would like to have an initial section in our forms where our clients need to input their code. If it is valid then the rest of the form is shown to them, if not they cannot proceed further.

I looked around here and google support, but I couldn't find a way to validate using a query.
Did I miss something?

If there is no way to do it like this, what would be the most accessible and most straightforward path?

We are using google Forms since it is convenient, and I'm the only programmer in my group, so I would like to leave things as easy as possible for my colleagues without them needing to code anything.
The ideal would be to have a one-button addon on google form which generates the section (or HTML page) automatically.

EDIT: More specific question

Comment: I'm don't understand your question completely but I'm guessing you will want to look at UrlFetchApp.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

Comment: What would this validation passage look like in a google form and more importantly what does it do?  AFAIK there is no way for Google Forms to generate a query and take the results of that query and do anything with it.  All that has to be accomplish before the form is built

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ALTERNATIVE WORKAROUND *[UPDATED]*

- As what **Cooper** has mentioned on the comments, it is impossible for Google Forms to run a website check/query before the user gets directed or not to the actual Google Form, depending on the check.
- Upon reviewing, the `URL` validation only checks if the inputted text value is in correct URL format e.g. `https://example.com` & it seems there's nothing more that you can do with it.

Perhaps you can try this updated workaround that uses a combination of using [Web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html#serve_html_as_a_web_app), Apps Script functions & [HTML redirection](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

### How it works?

> You'll need to create a web-app URL using Apps Script that will run first the `input.html` web-page. The web-page will ask user to input the `CODE` to complete your database query via your URL  `www.mydatabase.com/q=CODE`. Then, the script will decide if the complete database URL with inputted `CODE` returns a non-empty JSON value, user gets routed to the Google Form. If not, nothing will happen & user will get a browser alert that says `Code is not valid`.

**Note:** I'd also like to give you a heads up that **this is just a workaround** & it has a limitation as users can still have the ability to copy the actual Google Form link as this is just a redirection of URL.

### Script Code

```
function checkSite(c){
  try{
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("www.mydatabase.com/q="+c); //to complete your database query. Just edit this with your actual URL
    var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    if(Object.keys(data).length > 0){
      return true; //if URL returns JSON value
    }
    return false; //if URL returns empty JSON value
  }catch(e){
    return false;
  }
}

function passCode(code){
  return checkSite(code);
}

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('input');
}
```

### input.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script> 
      function passData(){
        var code = document.getElementById("inputCode").value; //<-- PASS THIS DATA TO GOOGLE SCRIPT (The .gs file)
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).passCode(code);
      }

      function onSuccess(result) {
        route(result);
      }

      function route(result) {
        if(result == true){
          alert("Routing to Google Form");
          window.location.href="https://YOUR_GOOGLE_FORMS_LINK";  
        }
        alert("Code is invalid");
      }

      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div align="center">
        <label for="code">Input Code:</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputCode" name="inputCode"><br><br>
        <button onclick='passData()' id="btnContinue">Continue</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Sample Result

- Here's how the `input.html` web-page looks like

> [image]

- *If the `CODE` on the URL query returns a non empty JSON value, user gets a browser alert that says `Routing to Google Form`, then user finally gets routed to the Google Form*

> [image]
> [image]

- *Otherwise, user gets a browser alert that says `Code is invalid` and it will never route user to the Google Form*

> [image]

Comment: URL of form can be copied and sent to anyone. Not recommended to use. > "Security through obscurity aims to secure a system by deliberately hiding or concealing its security flaws."

Comment: Thank you! This seems like a good workaround. 
But is it possible to have the HTML page ask the user for the unique code and check?
Moreover, my colleagues do not know how to use appscript, so is it possible to generate the true.html with an addon? Where you need to specify the form link, and it automatically outputs the correct true.html?

Comment: The HTML file is just a simple page & it would be very complex to have the page ask users for a unique code as you need to connect to a third-party database or any services to do that process. Also, it wouldn't make sense to generate the `true.html` as an add-on since it is just a simple webpage. You need to specify the form link on the `true.html` file (just replace the 2 lines with `https://GOOGLE_DOCS FORM_URL` with the actual `https://` link of your actual Google Form). On the sample script, the `doGet(e)` will output the `true.html` if the condition is met.

Comment: I think I wasn't really clear in my question, so I updated it with more infos

Comment: I have updated my answer. Upon reviewing article you've shared, the URL validation only checks if the inputted text value is in correct URL format e.g. `https://example.com` & it seems there's nothing more that you can do with it.

Comment: Thanks again!
I guess this is as close as it can get. Is there no way to create the HTML page automatically from a google form addon?
Everything in the HTML page would remain the same but the actual form link.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, I think using this html as an add-on is not possible with this implementation.